# How to show upload progress from server to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, progress-bar

I'm creating system which allows you to upload videos. Basically user uploads video to my server, and then it uploads from my server to Amazon s3 server.

Is there any way to show user upload progress? It's easy to show progress while uploading to my server, what about to S3?

Comment: how you upload from your server to s3 server ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the exec function to measure the file size

Something like this

```
exec("ls -l /path/ | grep 'filename'", $file);
```

Then parse the $file to extract the file size

Compare to total file size and calculating a percentage is elementary

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, what exactly is the problem, can you clarify what problems you are encountering and what has been tried so far?

Comment: Step 1. User uploads video to Server A - He can see progress bar
Step 2. Video is converted on server A - He can see progress bar
Step 3. Coverted video is uploading to AWS S3 , but I have no idea how should I get status on uploading, how much I've already uploaded...

Comment: Get the filesize on Server A, that tells you the total size of the file
Get the filesize on AWS, that tells you the amount that has uploaded